# cygwin åäö in emacs

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I been bugging with this problem for some hours now. And I couldn't find the answer on google so I try it here.

The problem is that when I run emacs in cygwin in `-nw` mode characters like åäö doesn't come out normally. However it is perfectly normal when I type those character in mintty terminal. The answer that I found on google is that I should type `M-x standard-display-european` however emacs doesn't have that option. It only found `standard-display-cyrillic-translit`

Comment: What exactly does go wrong with those characters? Does it affect newly created files or existing files?

Comment: And which Cygwin version are you using? (`uname -r` will tell you.)

Comment: @ak - i'm using 1.7.x. Those character will show up as blocks. It will show as blocks when I use `cat` as well.

Comment: Right. So are you looking at an existing file there? It probably means that that file is encoded in a legacy encoding such as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252, whereas Cygwin 1.7 uses UTF-8 (i.e. Unicode) by default. Can you type the special characters when creating a new file in emacs?

Comment: @ak - I have tried both. When creating a new file with emacs (cygwin) and when I type in those characters it will show as blocks. However when I open the file with notepad (windows) it will be viewed as correct characters.

Comment: Hmm. Where are you running emacs? In mintty or in the default console? If the latter, try choosing a TrueType font such as Lucida Console in the console properties.

Comment: @ak - i'm using mintty which I have set from beginning to use Consolas. Now I have also tried with using Lucida Console on mintty and the default console with the same result. It still print blocks in emacs, but `åäö` is viewed perfectly ok when typing on the console. However I get \303\245 as response from bash when I hit enter after `å`

Comment: That looks like inconsistent charset settings then. What are locale and character set on the Text page of mintty's options set to, and what are the values of the `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE`, and `LANG` environment variables? Are you setting those variables in bash startup files? If so, don't, because the terminal won't get to know about it.

Comment: It works fine for me. What does `locale` output?

Comment: Yep, works fine for me too. Another question: are you actually using Cygwin emacs, and are you doing anything charset-related in emacs settings?

Comment: when typing `locale` I get C.UTF-8 for every variable except for `LC_ALL`. I haven't set anything that I am aware of that will change the locale when I start up bash. I had some few lines in `.inputrc` before e.g. `set meta-flag on` but I have removed them now.

Comment: @ak2 - yes I am using cygwin emacs. I installed it using the setup file downloaded from cygwin.

Comment: works for me. cygwin 1.7.9, emacs 23.3.1, mintty 1.0.1
http://i.imgur.com/sCmS9.png